# ios charts framework value overlap

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

[image: Problem:]

How can I avoid overlap issue of first value

and, how can I see last value that clipped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a few options between modify styling on your axes and adjusting the viewport.

I would try:

**Disable left axis, enable right axis**

```
chart.leftAxis.drawValuesEnabled = false
chart.rightAxis.drawValuesEnabled = true
```

**Modify viewport**

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Modifying-the-Viewport

```
chart.setExtraOffsets()
```

**Custom value formatting**

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-ValueFormatter-interface

991234 becomes 991K (shorter and easy-to-read)

```
chart.xAxis.valueFormatter = ...
```

Comment: It is iOS-Charts framework, but it helped. Thank you very much!